# default index.rmd codes shown empty in blogdown using Rstudio

Tags: rstudio, netlify, blogdown

When I try to create my first personal website using `blogdown` in Rstudio, I start with `File -> New Project -> New Directory ->website using blogdown` with the default theme. Then I used to run `blogdown::serve_site()` from the console and I get the site for R markdown. Unfortunately, when I open `index.rmd` from content, the codes are empty to edit to my own code. not only index.rmd but all others like `about`, `config.yaml`... are not shown from the editor window. When I click it, pops up with an empty script window.

What shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

However, it works when I try it using  `File -> Reopen with Encoding -> UTF-8`.

I also try to change the default  Encoding system as:  `Tools -> Global Options -> code -> Savings -> Default Text Encoding to UTF-8` and still not working. The only solution is always using the `File -> Reopen with Encoding -> UTF-8` path, even to open locally saved script files.

I think the problem happened during install the new R 4.2.0.